# How to integrate $\int \frac{1-v}{v^2+2v+2}dv$?

Tags: integration

How does one integrate $\int \frac{1-v}{v^2+2v+2}dv$?

I tried the method of splitting the fraction into partial fractions but the denominator cannot be factorised.

Comment: you do not need to factor the denominator, rewrite it as $(v+1)^2+1$

Comment: @Vasya May I know what is it about the equation that makes you know rewriting as $(v+1)^2 + 1$ works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ I = \int \frac{1-x}{x^2+2x+2} dx = \int \frac{1-x}{(x+1)^2+1} dx$$
Then substitute $y = x+1, dy = dx$, to get
$$ I = \int\frac{2-y}{y^2+1}dy = 2 \arctan(x+1)-\frac{1}{2}\log(x^2+2x+2)+C$$

Answer (score 1):

Try to consider it as $(v+1)^2+1$ and then you have $$\dfrac{1-v}{v^2+2v+2}=\dfrac{-0.5(2v+2)}{v^2+2v+2}+\dfrac{2}{\underbrace{v^2+2v+2}_{(v+1)^2+1}}$$